# semigroups defined on banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a Banach space and $Z:=\{Z(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is strongly continuous semigroup defined on it. 
If $X$ turns out to be a Banach Algebra, i.e. for $x,y\in X$, $xy\in X$. Is $Z$ still defined on $X$? If yes, how $Z(t)$ will operate on the product $xy$? As I expect it to be like
$$Z(t)[xy]= [Z(t)x][Z(t)y]$$ 
It would be great if someone can provide me with proper reference.

Comment: If $X=\mathbb{C}$ and $Z(t):\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, with $Z(t)(x)=e^tx$, $x\in X$, then $Z(t)(xy)=e^txy\neq(e^tx)(e^ty)=\left(Z(t)(x)\right)\left(Z(t)(y)\right)$.

Comment: thank you for your effort.